# Make flag default behavior for git command (commit and rebase)

Tags: git

I want to specify the flag `--keep-empty` and `--allow-empty` to be the default behavior for `rebase` and `commit`, respectively. Is there a way to do this?

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to do this with `git config`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

I only want to do this for a specific repo, so I want to avoid aliasing the command in bash.

I *especially* want to do this for `rebase`, as there's the high probability of erasing important, but empty, commits by accident.

Comment: Wait..git aliasing can be repo-specific.  Like `git config --local --add "alias.rebase" "rebase --allow-empty"`

Comment: Honestly, I didn't realize I could set an alias through git, I was thinking a bash alias. That solution looks like it will work

Comment: Actually...I don't think it will...more in my answer which I will delete soon

Comment: Yeah it's not working for me, unfortunatly

Comment: "To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored"  Which explains why my `alias.grep=grep -I` never worked (don't grep binary files)